# Using Silverlight authorization to manage access to individual controls

Tags: silverlight, autoresize, restrictions

I am making an application using Silverlight.

I must restict the access of some controls to some users.

Example: user1 can't use the delete button ...

Is there a framework or something that can help me ? 
Would it help if I use sessions ?

Thanks.

Comment: This previous answer of mine might be of help:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994311/windows-authentication-in-silverlight-vs-2010/3998940#3998940][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994311/windows-authentication-in-silverlight-vs-2010/3998940#3998940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tool that do what I want. It is called **Visual Guard**. It's a very nice and powerful tool.

In the [documentation](http://www.visual-guard.com/download/GS_VG8_PB_US.pdf)

> Visual Guard has been designed to automate as much functionality as 
>   possible in order to manage security in a PowerBuilder application. 
>   This is performed at several levels:
>
> Managing actions specific to PowerBuilder  Visual Guard manages the
>   modification of key PowerBuilder object  properties:  •
>   Enabling/disabling a control (button, graph, listbox, etc.). ).  •
>   Making a control (button, graph, listbox, etc.) visible/invisible.   •
>   Enabling/disabling menu items.  • Making menu items as well as their
>   toolbar icons visible/invisible.  • Hiding/showing a datawindow
>   column.  • Enabling/disabling a datawindow column  • Changing the
>   WHERE clause of a datawindow sql statement.  • Filtering of rows
>   displayed in a datawindow.  • Modifying text controls (Column names,
>   contextual help, etc.)  • Modifying the properties of a datawindow
>   element (data input  restrictions, changing a column's validation
>   message or validation  rules, etc.).
>
> Managing actions specific to your class libraries
>
> Data-driven Security

and much much more

I hope that it will help someone